# Is there a way to convert soap request to rest with "base64Binary" parameter?

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 AM for transforming SOAP services to Rest. When I entered the WSDL file, the parameters that are base64Binary did not add to resources, and the error "Token "base64Binary" does not exist." appeared. I added that parameter manually, but it did not change. this error also appeared when I test the method in the devportal.

error: Resolver error at paths./login.post.parameters.0.schema.properties.Login.properties.MAC.$ref
Could not resolve reference: #/definitions/base64Binary

Please help me and thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePvP0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnGcP.png)
the way to correct the fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've added this code instead of base64Binary and it works, but in the 4.1.0 version. in the others, the problem is still there and I think this is a bug.

Mac:

```
    type: string

    format: byte

    description: MAC

    pattern: '^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$'
```